# What skill is used to recognise someone?

Tags: skills, dresden-files

Consider for example a character hears a voice recording of someone, such as a recording that a journalist made of an interview. Later the character coincidentally meets someone who spoke in that recording.

What should they be called to roll to see if they can recognise the character by the voice they heard, or to see if they don't pick up on it?

I'm uncertain which of the skills in the official mechanics of the system would be the one that's supposed to be used. The mental skills of Discipline or Conviction don't seem appropriate as described. But I don't think the usual “knowing people” skill of Contacts is either.

Comment: Are you sure you need a skill check for that ? Have you considered just giving the information ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It's probably Alertness, but it depends how you frame it.

> **Passive Awareness (Alertness)**
>
> [... Alertness is] appropriate for things that you do not expect or are not looking for.
>
> -- Dresden Files, "Your Story", p.121

Detective Raphael Ambrosius Costeau has two skills that use his senses to get information from the world. Alertness is "passive" and Investigation is "active", both in that he will rarely deliberately roll Alertness to do something, and in that using Investigation to do something involves a scene where he makes a much larger expenditure of time and effort to be sure of his conclusions than just talking to someone briefly.

So, realizing that someone he meets by coincidence matches a voice he heard before is *probably* not something he expects or is looking for, and is best handled by Alertness.

But I do say "probably". If Det. Costeau took the time to listen to the tape closely because he wanted to be able to identify the voices again in the future, then Investigation is a more appropriate skill to roll, though it should probably have been rolled at the time of the scene where he listened to the tape. But as a GM, there's no harm in correcting things in the moment like this, as long it's done to keep up with the narrative.

It also might be possible that the character Det. Costeau is meeting has something to hide - for example, trying to project a different public persona than the more candid voice the detective heard on the tape. In that case, Empathy could also be appropriate here - it doesn't have a "passive social awareness" trapping like Alertness, and its "active" trapping requires more close personal interaction than listening to a tape, but it *is* a passive defense against Deceive. Passive Awareness is there to clue you in on things that might be difficult to notice but aren't necessarily actively being concealed, but if someone's trying to hide social cues from you, that's much more of an active process.

Always keep in mind that **you and your table have the final judgment** about what skills are appropriate to do what things (see "Your Story" p.318 for that). But having a good understanding of the existing trappings is important in order to be able to make that judgment, and as far as existing trappings go, Passive Awareness is the least complicated match for what you've described.

Comment: Alertness is probably the best, but Empathy is also worth mentioning. A character that has much greater Empathy might have been paying closer attention to their voice, etc. I'd personally allow either (or Investigation as you've described).

Comment: @Ifusaso Thanks for mentioning Empathy, I realized something that might be common to this kind of scenario.